# Android following class could not be found

Tags: android

I'am trying to load a spinner to my layout and keep geting this error:

The following classes could not be found:
- Spinner (Change to android.widget.Spinner, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

heres my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spn_dates"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="displayDatesToSpiner" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/LST_bought_products"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="302dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to clean the project

Comment: Or to restart Eclipse: the graphical layout plugin may be stuck somewhere.

Comment: none of the above worked

Comment: i am also stuck at this problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when you rename the standard AppTheme in your android manifest. It will build and deploy just fine, but the xml design editor won't render it.

Answer (score -1):

This is usually because there's an invalid attribute somewhere.
Remove the onClick and it will work.

Comment: Try removing all attributes and leave out the id and layout attributes and see if that fixes it.